# Removing top/bottom margin from ggplot map after coord_equal()

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2

I'm using R 3.1.2 on Fedora 20 and having trouble with large blank areas at the top and bottom of maps produced by ggplot() when coord_equal() is used. Looking at this code:

```
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)
jp <- map_data("world",region=c("Japan"))
options <- par(mar=c(0,0,0,0),oma=c(0,0,0,0))
g <- ggplot(jp,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group,fill=region))
g <- g + geom_polygon(colour="black")
g <- g + labs(x=NULL,y=NULL)
#g <- g + coord_equal(ratio=1/2)
g <- g + theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.text.y=element_blank())
g <- g + theme(plot.background=element_rect(fill="lightblue"))
g
```

What you see with the coord_equal() line commented out is a map of Japan that fills the output area. However if you uncomment the coord_equal():

```
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)
jp <- map_data("world",region=c("Japan"))
options <- par(mar=c(0,0,0,0),oma=c(0,0,0,0))
g <- ggplot(jp,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group,fill=region))
g <- geom_polygon(colour="black")
g <- g + labs(x=NULL,y=NULL)
g <- g + coord_equal(ratio=1/2)
g <- g + theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.text.y=element_blank())
g <- g + theme(plot.background=element_rect(fill="lightblue"))
g
```

what happens is that the map panel is transformed to be half the height (same width), as is seen clearly by the light blue fill. The trouble is that the plot area does not change, so in effect what you get are large blank regions on the top and bottom of the plot. Using par(mar) has no effect, since these aren't margins, but obviously if the plot is included in a document they'll look like huge, unnecessary margins.

Are there options I can use that would prevent these blank regions from appearing (or trim them after the fact)? I should say that this is just a minimal example. "In real life" the map is more complex, and has to be generated on the fly. That said, the coordinates and dimensions of the panel should not change, so a possible hack would be to generate the image, then clip out the part I need. Still, much better if such things could be avoided.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This only seems to be a problem when working interactively. If you use `ggsave`, to actually save the resulting image, that solves the issue. The following actually leads to the same result regardless of the setting of `coord_equal(ratio=1/2)`:

```
ggsave('japan.png', height=5, width=10, plot=g)
```

[image]

Comment: That's very interesting. It seems to imply that ggplot() does have this capability... it's just a matter of figuring out how to access it!